# asp.net + ajax how can I

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

what I'm trying to do is I have three buttons as a menu and when I squeeze a button shows where an employee works (company, department, etc..), and  can edit it, if Prees the second button to display the employee's family and can be edited and when I pressed the third button to display the sales of the employee, all in one page

how can achieve that with asp.net

with mvc I can use partial views with ajax and in a page I call a partial view I need but in asp.net iam not find a example just using UpdatePanel Control but dont understand who to do the get and post for that and don't know what is the best way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look the steps you can follow to make this.

1. You create three Panels and in each Panel you place the information you say (work, family, sales etc)
2. You set all panels to hidden, except the first one. When the user click on a button you simple change the views of this panels, and maybe make some calculations, data access etc.
3. You place all of that inside an update panel to make it work with ajax.

Other way is to use the `TabContainer`

Here is one other example that use the TabContainer, is the same idea, little more automatic.

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/Tabs-Control.ashx

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=178